# receive data from textbox and value from radiobutton c#

Tags: c#, radio-button

[image]

as you can see in the picture above, there is 3types of radio button and a textbox. for the user to search data, user need to fill in the textbox and choose the type to be search. This data will appear at the other form.

this is my code in search form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SliceLink
{
    public partial class SearchForm : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        string _radio;
        public string radio 
        {
            get { return this._radio;  }
            set { this._radio = value; }
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter keyword to search");
            else 
            {                              
                Form3 form3 = new Form3(textBox1.Text);
                form3.Show();   
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code to view in viewForm.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SliceLink
{
    public partial class ViewForm : Form
    {       
        public Form3(string sTEXT)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();            
            xml.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Patient/Patient/Name");
            //XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes(sTEXT);
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string name = xn.InnerText;                
                textBox1.Text = name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i can receive the user input fill in the `textbox` but i do not know how to retrieve what type user choose. is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

I would organize checking selected radio button next way:

1. For each radio button fill the `Tag` property with numeric values (0, 1, 2, etc.).
2. Create enum with corresponding values.
3. Set the same event handler for `Click` event of **all** radio buttons.
4. Check `Tag` value of `sender` radio button in the event handler.

So, here is the sample code of form:

```
internal enum SearchType
{
    All = 0, Date = 1, Id = 2
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private SearchType _selectedSearchType = SearchType.All;

    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use _selectedSearchType to do search.
    }

    private void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedSearchType = (SearchType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SearchType), ((Control)sender).Tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Benefits:** you can easily add any number of radio buttons, change them, etc. without changing backing code. And you can use selected value without any *knowledge* about radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `enum` type for the different options, then create a public `property` on the form containing the radiobuttons and depending on which one is selected return the corresponding `enum` value.

So you'll get something like:

```
public enum FindType { DATE, ID, ALL }
```

in your `SearchForm`:

```
public FindType FindGrouping
{
   get
   {
      if (radioButtonDate.Checked)
         return FindType.DATE;
      // ... etc.
}
```

And retrieve the value in your `ViewForm` with `searchFormInstance.FindGrouping;`

Comment: Good call! I went for quick 'n dirty! ;)